# How to un-escape a String after using sqlEscapeString()

Tags: android, sqlite, escaping

So I was searching to find the easiest and most efficient ways to escape malicious Strings in SQLite for my app. Most answers on here usually have something along the regular expressions route. I stumbled upon one answer that found [sqlEscapeString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString%28java.lang.String%29).

There is one problem. When it escapes it, it seems to also add single quotes on the ends of the String, so its goes from this: `Test's` to: `'Test''s'`. Now I don't really know why its even doing that, but I was hoping someone new of a function that exists in Android that does the opposite. `DatabaseUtils` does not seem to have the companion function for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the most efficient way to protect against malicious string is to simply let SQLite do the job. Android wraps that functionality and uses a `ContentValues`,  `String[]`, or `Object[]` parameter, depending on which method you use to query databases, to hold the escapted values.:

[SQLiteDatabase.insert(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

[SQLiteDatabase.query(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

[SQLiteDatabase.update(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

[SQLiteDatabase.delete(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

[SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

In using the above methods, put a `?` in your SQL statement in place of the string you want to escape.

Comment: I was just about to tell you that ContentValues does not do that, but then I just realized, I have been inconsistent with how I enter things into those methods. I was using `rawQuery()` sometimes, and I just realized that. I will change the rawQuery's, and try it again. That would make so much more sense.

Comment: @Andy: I admit I haven't made much use of the `insert` method as I always use `execSQL`, but I expect `insert` (and others) to take care of the escaping when using the `ContentValues` parameter (and others). I'm not sure what you meant in your comment, but are you sure that string parameters aren't escaped in the `ContentValues` argument?

Comment: @Andy: sorry about that I just realized you want to 'unescape'. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Oh, you helped solve my issue! The problem was that as I was learning, I changed some of my code up, specifically with using the projections and selections of the ContentProvider functions. Before I was using `rawQuery()`. Meaning that some of my code depended on passing info back and forth, but since rawQuery doesn't actually bind things, it caused my error. I realized after you mentioned it that my issue was there. So that was my fault. Thanks for that since you are the reason I caught that bug :)

Comment: I am not using rawQuery(). Implemented SQLite database using Content Providers. Static scan reports throws SQL Injection flaw in my Content Provider class. Everyone suggests I need to sanitize the variables I pass into selectionArgs array.

Do you guys have any idea how do I sanitize the variables?

Answer (score 2):

I've made a unescape() method for reverse sqlEscapeString().

```
public String unescapeString(String string) {
    if (string == null)
        return null;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);

    sb = sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    sb = sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

    return sb.toString().replaceAll("''", "'");
}
```

Comment: Looking at the Android source for 4.4.4, this does appear to be a perfect reverse method.